# Custom Permissions Verification Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out the best way to write a custom permission in Django Rest Framework for the following use case.

I have a `User` model and a `Organization` model. A `User` can have multiple `Organizations` and an `Organization` can have multiple `Users`. I have this model to connect the relationships:

```py
class UserOrganization(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Owner")
    primary_org = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Users are able to create integrations to third party services, but these are tied to both the `User` and the `Organization`. I currently have the following custom permission that checks the `User` but how do I check if they are a member of the `Organization`?

```py
class UserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Deny actions on objects if the user is not authenticated
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return False

        if view.action == 'retrieve':
            return obj.user == request.user or request.user.is_admin
        elif view.action in ['update', 'partial_update']:
            return obj.user == request.user or request.user.is_admin
        elif view.action == 'destroy':
            return request.user.is_admin
        else:
            return False
```

The `Organization` id will be passed with every API call. Here's the Viewset for adding a new integration

```py
class IntegrationViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                         mixins.ListModelMixin,
                         mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                         mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                         viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Integration.objects.filter(user=user)

    serializer_class = IntegrationSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

How can I check the `User` is also a member of the `Organization` before allowing any read/create/update to happen?

Comment: if you have the organization object, then you can do `organization.userorganization_set.filter(user=request.user)` , it's not really clear since you didn't post both models

Comment: @alex I do have that model, just in the permission class how do I get the organization from the request and check the `UserOrganization` model?

Comment: like @alex wrote just reverse `self.request.user.userorganization_set.filter(organization__in=(1,2,3,4))`. You can also just check for one id  `.filter(organization=1)`